# Insert Latitude and Longitude Programmatically for Reverse Geolocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have a Situation ,where i am pulling the Latitude and Longitude from a XML file ,Parsing and Displaying it .and i am successfully be able to Do it in Two Different UILabels .but now i need to the Location and Display it in a Label.Can someone suggest me how to achieve that , i have this code , but its only let me to select the Value of Coordinates from Simulator only .

```
- (IBAction)geoCodeLocation:(id)sender{

 //Geocoding Block
[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: 
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {



     //Get nearby address
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

     //String to hold address
     NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

     //Print the location to console
     NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);

     //Set the label text to current location
     [locationLabel setText:locatedAt];

 }];
}
```

Suggestion  : this Question is not about XML parsing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.78583400      longitude:-122.40641700];

[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: location completionHandler: 
^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

 //Get nearby address
 CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

 //String to hold address
 locatedAtcountry = placemark.country;
 locatedAtcity = placemark.locality;
 locatedAtisocountry = placemark.ISOcountryCode;

 //Print the location to console
 NSLog(@"Estas en %@",locatedAtcountry);
 NSLog(@"Estas en %@",locatedAtcity);
 NSLog(@"Estas en %@",locatedAtisocountry);

 [cityLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",locatedAtcity]];
 [locationLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",locatedAtcountry]];

 //Set the label text to current location
 //[locationLabel setText:locatedAt];

}];
```